# Windows 7: Specify which (internal) drives to mount on startup

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, mount

I am running a machine with Windows 7 and multiple internal hard drives/partitions on these drives - booting from one of these.

All of these drives/partitions are mounted on startup. Is there a way to tell the system to only mount specific volumes (in my case: only the boot volume), i.e. to exclude other drives?

I could only find information on network drives (which do **not** seem to mount on launch by default). Any help appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Esteban: not yet, but I haven't been trying for some time...

Comment: So I'm not sure if not having a drive letter the same as not being mounted in Windows, but for me it's good enough. Once you remove the drive letter in Windows (one way of doing it is simply going to Computer Management under Administrative Tools), it keeps the partition without it after restart.